# metaclass conflict with single inheritance

Tags: python, django, metaclass

I'm doing a single inheritance subclass for a django admin class like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth import admin as auth_admin

class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):
   pass
```

And I'm getting the error: "metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"

I think I understand what the error is complaining about - but I'm not clear on why I'm getting it with only a single ancestor. Every other time I've seen this error, it's because I'm using multiple inheritance. What could the single ancestor's class metaclass be conflicting with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be unrelated to the actual admin class - The form used for add_form must be a subclass of ModelForm - in this case it was just a plain Form. When added to the page django introspects the form and attempts to inject a class in if it's not a ModelForm, leading the to the metatype mismatch.

Comment: But in the above case the code doesn't even call `add_form`, and still it raised the exception? Btw glad the issue is resolve—feel free to accept your answer, so the question doesn't remain in the unanswered state.

Comment: add_form is a property - I'm guessing that the metaclass for the admin class attempts to create the form, so the conflict happens when the class is defined.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if an incorrect metaclass is getting chosen for `UserAdmin`, for example by `__metaclass__` somehow getting inserted into the dict of the nascent class. Try the following test:

```
# force the correct metaclass:
metaclass = type(auth_admin.UserAdmin)
UserAdmin = metaclass("UserAdmin", (auth_admin.UserAdmin,), {})
```

If this works, it means a metaclass other than `type(auth_admin.UserAdmin)` is getting picked in your `class` statement. The culprit should be revealed by grepping Django sources and mixins for `__metaclass__`.

If this fails with the same error, it could be that the metaclass constructor is doing some class construction of its own, which fails because of a genuine multiple inheritance error. In that case, a stack trace should reveal where this occurs.